Overheating the laptop while developing a Laravel application
When I open one of the Laravel programs with vscode, my laptop heats up severely, and the battery charge also decreases rapidly. This only happens with one of the programs, which is not significantly larger than the others. Everything else seems normal.
My operating system is Ubuntu 22.04.
I also once removed all extensions, but nothing changed.
this is composer.json of program:
 "require": { "php": "^8.1", "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2", "laravel/framework": "^10.10", "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3", "laravel/tinker": "^2.8", "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1", "spatie/laravel-permission": "^6.3", "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^10.11" }, "require-dev": { "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.13", "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1", "laravel/breeze": "^1.28", "laravel/pint": "^1.0", "laravel/sail": "^1.18", "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4", "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0", "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1", "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0" },

I made it myself.
After many efforts, I cloned the app from GitHub to another folder and continued development from there :)
That old folder still has a problem...

My guess is that your VS Code is indexing files in vendor and/or node_modules folders. Make sure you have them gitignored and that your VS Code skips gitignored files.
